# DevExpress GridColumn strange proportional sizing

Tags: devexpress-wpf, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have created a `GridControl` with a few fixed width and 2 autowidth columns.

I have set the autowidth columns like this:

```
<dxg:GridColumn
  Width="2*" FieldName="Name"
  FixedWidth="False" Header="Name" />

<dxg:GridColumn
  Width="6*" FieldName="Subject"
  FixedWidth="False" Header="Subject" />
```

I intended to have a 2:6 proportion regarding the widths of those columns, so I set their `Width` to 6* and 2* as proportional values.

Strangely, the following happens.

When they are set to 6* and 2*:

[image]

When they are set to 5* and 2*:

[image]

Clearly, if the multiplier is below 6, it works as there are no multipliers (the columns fill equally the remaining space), but when it is over 5, the proportion goes mad and shrinks the lower multiplied column.

According to their [support](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q237952/grid-column-provide-a-way-to-set-the-column-width-relative-to-other-columns), it supports proportional settings.

How can I create a 6:2 proportion without setting a MaxWidth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to set `AutoWidth` property of `TableView` to `False`, it should then work as expected. Also, I believe you don't need to set `FixedWidth` on columns (it only works in AutoWidth mode).

Hope this helps!